# AWS API Gateway: Forward Result Policy From Lambda Authenticator to Backend

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using a custom authenticator (Lambda) to validate Javascript Web Tokens (JWT) for a backend Node.js API on Amazon's API Gateway.

Is there a way to pass the policy generated from Lambda to the backend API through a header? The JWTs contain some information that I want the API backend to access, without having to re-validate the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: You can use the principalId as mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)

> You can access the principalId value in a mapping template using the
>   $context.authorizer.principalId variable. This is useful if you want
>   to pass the value to the back end. For more information, see Accessing
>   the $context Variable.